# Unable to make HTTP request to Laravel endpoint

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having a really strange issue when trying to make a HTTP request in one of my tests. My `api.php` routes file looks like this:

```
$router->group(['prefix' => '/v1', 'middleware' => ['auth:api']], 
    function (\Illuminate\Routing\Router $router) {
        $router->apiResource('/contacts', 'ContactsController');

        $router->group(['prefix' => '/contacts'], 
            function (\Illuminate\Routing\Router $router) {
                $router->apiResource('/groups', 'Contacts\\GroupsController');
        });
});
```

Running `php artisan route:list` shows the following route as being registered

```
+------------+------------------------+--------------+------------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|   Method   |           URI          |      Name    |                        Action                        |   Middleware   |
+------------+------------------------+--------------+------------------------------------------------------+----------------+
| GET|HEAD   | api/v1/contacts/groups | groups.index | App\Http\Controllers\Contacts\GroupsController@index |  api auth:api  |
+------------+------------------------+--------------+------------------------------------------------------+----------------+
```

However when I run my test, I get a 404 response. The test is as follows:

```
public function testICanGetAllOfTheGroups()
{
    factory(Group::class)->times(3)->create();

    $this->json('GET', '/api/v1/contacts/groups')
            ->assertStatus(200)->assertJsonCount(3);
}
```

I have also tried running `php artisan route:clear` and `php artisan cache:clear` but it hasn't made a difference.

For authentication, I have created the following trait which I am using.

```
trait Authenticated
{
    /** @var \App\Models\User */
    protected $user;

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->user = factory(User::class)->create();
        Passport::actingAs($this->user);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appear to have figured this out. If I re-arrange the routes from

```
$router->group(['prefix' => '/v1', 'middleware' => ['auth:api']], function (\Illuminate\Routing\Router $router) {
    $router->apiResource('/contacts', 'ContactsController');

    $router->group(['prefix' => '/contacts'], function (\Illuminate\Routing\Router $router) {
        $router->apiResource('/groups', 'Contacts\\GroupsController');
    });
});
```

to

```
$router->group(['prefix' => '/v1', 'middleware' => ['auth:api']], function (\Illuminate\Routing\Router $router) {
    $router->group(['prefix' => '/contacts'], function (\Illuminate\Routing\Router $router) {
        $router->apiResource('/groups', 'Contacts\\GroupsController');
    });

    $router->apiResource('/contacts', 'ContactsController');
});
```

It then works. I suspect this is a bug with how Laravel is registering it's routes as `POST` and `PUT` requests still work fine.

I have raised this as a bug on GitHub - https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/26038

---

**UPDATE**

I have now identified the issue. Basically the `apiResource` translates one of the endpoints to:

`/contacts/{contact}`.

Following on from that one of the routes is `contacts/groups`. However in order for Laravel to match it with `contacts/groups` it needs to be before `/contacts/{contact}` as it is a wildcard. Whether or not it is intentional behaviour I'm not sure, but at the moment just having the routes the other way around fixes this.

Answer (score 0):

why dont you put both routes in the `contacts` group ?

```
$router->group(['prefix' => '/v1', 'middleware' => ['auth:api']], function (\Illuminate\Routing\Router $router) {
    $router->group(['prefix' => '/contacts'], function (\Illuminate\Routing\Router $router) {
        $router->apiResource('/', 'ContactsController');
        $router->apiResource('/groups', 'Contacts\\GroupsController');
    });
});
```

Comment: If I do that, my tests then fail as I get a 404 response for `index`, `update` and `show` methods. Looking at `php artisan route:list` it does not register these routes correctly when doing this.

Comment: and with the `/` in `$router->apiResource('/', 'ContactsController');`

Comment: Same thing happens with the `/`